# Hibernate get record by matching value with 2 concat fields

Tags: hibernate, criteria

I have a value which must be matched with 2 fields concatenation( value = field1+field2) and return result object matching that criteria. Can I somehow do it via Criteria or I need to use Query to resolve this ?

Thank you for answering.

Comment: Did you try "from MyObj o where (o.field1 + o.field2) = value"?

Comment: Yes it works using HSQL and Query , but I wanted to know if its possibly to do it using Criteria object...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hibernate doesn't have this functionality implemented.
There are some ways of doing this.

One is using a SQLRestriction, which is database dependent.
Another one is creating a field with a concatenate formula, also DB dependent.

I fixed the problem by creating a new Criterion for Hibernate.
You can read more about it, here.
http://whaticode.com/2013/02/01/hibernate-criteria-concatenate-fields-in-like-and-ilike-operators/

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is not very elegant, but it works:

result.add(Restrictions.ilike("dni || this.letter", "%" + dniWithLetter + "%"));

Comment: result is a Criteria, obviusy